# Finding the nth prime number without 'break' in Python

Tags: python

I'm quite new to coding and I'm being asked to write code to find the nth prime number in Python. I managed to writing the following code:

```
prime = input("which prime do you want to find?:")

n = 0
for x in range(2, 8000):
    for y in range (2, x):
        if (x % y) == 0:
            break
    else:
        n = n + 1
    if n == prime:
        print(x)
        break
```

However, I just found out I'm not allowed to use break. They're essentially only allowing me 'for' and 'while' loops. Does anyone have any inkling on how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What does "not allowed" mean? Who are "they"?

Comment: Just my teachers, I'm a first years physics student

Comment: Not being able to use 'break' is silly.  If you can use a 'for' loop, using 'break' is basically part of using a 'for' loop.  Are you sure that you can't do what you show?  It doesn't make any sense to me that your teachers would disallow what you've done.   With that said...it IS possible to use a `while` loop instead of a `for` loop and then not use `break`.  I don't see the point to this though.

Comment: Did you try **asking them** how they intend for the solution to work, or why they think `break` is inappropriate here?

Comment: Honestly, it's just crazy, I can't think of a good reason why my teachers are like this sadly.

Comment: What would be an example of how I could imitate a for-loop with break, using 'while' without break?

Comment: See my answer for an example

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do this with `while` loops and no use of `break`:

```
# Let's find the first prime equal to or greater than the number input by the user

# Get the user's input
prime = input("which prime do you want to find?:")

found = False
x = 2
# While we haven't found the prime we're looking for and we haven't reached our upper limit...
while not found and x < 8000:
    # See if we can find any factors for 'x', the next number we're considering
    y = 2
    while not found and y < x:
        # While we haven't found a factor and still have more candidates...
        if (x % y) == 0:
            # We found a factor, so note that we have done so.  This will exit the inner
            # while loop that we're in.
            found = True
        else:
            # Not a factor, so try the next factor candidate
            y += 1
    if not found and x >= int(prime):
        # If we didn't find any factors, and the current candidate is equal to or
        # greater than the user's input, then 'x' is the prime we're looking for,
        # so set 'found' to True to exit the outer loop.
        found = True
    else:
        # Otherwise, make sure 'found' is false (it may already be) and move on to the next candidate
        found = False
        x += 1
        
print(x)
```

I think this version has some value.  It shows one reason why having `break` is valuable.  Not being able to use `break`, this solution is considerably more cumbersome since we have to explicitly keep track of the current values for each loop and we also have to test and set a flag to decide if we should keep iterating.  This is NOT the way this problem should be solved in the real world!  One should use `for` loops and `break` instead.